# How to import DVD's to iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipad, dvd

I will be traveling long haul over a few times over the next few weeks and would like to watch some TV series I have on DVD, using an iPad, but do not want to have to purchase it again on iTunes.

So, is it possible to burn a DVD into iTunes for later viewing on iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) to rip it to a file, then just copy to iTunes. Handbrake is free and has a very simple to use interface. Just select the DVD in the file browser,  choose a preset and you'll be on your way.

[image: Handbrake]

Answer (score 0):

iTunes doesn't support ripping DVDs itself, but you can use other software to do so, then import the file into iTunes and sync it to your device.

## [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

Handbrake supports many formats and includes presets for many types of devices (to optimize resolution & quality for performance).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Handbrake is a very nice, but somewhat difficult tool to use.  You've got to also download VLC, and if you get the newest version, you need an additional library.  It's not hard, but it's not point and click.  For that reason, I'm going to throw [RipIt](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) into the mix.  It's not free (there are free trials.) They're a small app developer, and it's a good product.  I use it for the few times Handbrake fails.